# Is it possible to have two browsers, one with Silverlight 3, one with Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-plugin

For development reasons, I can't install Silverlight 4 on a particular machine.

Is it possible to install the Silverlight 4 plugin on one browser, e.g. in Chrome or Opera, while Firefox and Explorer continue to use the Silverlight 3 plugin?

Comment: If you can't install Silverlight 3 on a particular machine why does it matter whether you can install both on a machine (I assume you mean a different machine)?

Answer (score 6):

Nope.  Just tried it.  The Silverlight installer installs the plugin for all installed browsers.  Can you run a virtual machine and install SL4 on that?

Answer (score 3):

Silly question, why not just install the Silverlight 4 runtime and continue to develop with the Silverlight 3 Development tools?

The Silverlight 4 runtime is (theoretically) 100% backwards compatible and can run any Silverlight 3 XAP.